# Why are there no clear types given on the Arduino API docs?

Tags: documentation

For exmaple, I look at the page for [digitalWrite](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/) and all I get is this for the signature:

```
digitalWrite(pin, value)
```

No return value type, no paramater type, nothing.

Instead, in a seperate section it says

```
Returns
Nothing
```

And then it says

```
Parameters
pin: the Arduino pin number.
value: HIGH or LOW.
```

What is "value"? An int? uint8_t? bool? Why is the API written in such a weird ambigious way?

I would expect something like

```
void digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t value)
```

Like I am used to from other "proper" API documentations.

Comment: Because it's written for novices by novices

Comment: I found `void digitalWrite(pin_size_t pinNumber, PinStatus status);`. that is why.

Comment: Most pages in Language/Functions _do_ document the data types (I count 74 out of 137). This is more than it used to be, as documenting the types is an ongoing effort. You may participate by sending pull requests to [arduino/reference-en](https://github.com/arduino/reference-en).

Comment: See [Specify data types in function definitions](https://github.com/arduino/reference-en/issues/15). I raised this issue in 2015 - that issue is still open 7 years later.

Comment: Try going to that Github page and supporting my request that the documentation be improved. Good luck!

Comment: re:"_What is "value"? An int? uint8_t? bool?_": all of those work in that context, so I don't see an issue.